# How to use `toYYYYMMDD(timestamp)` in primary key in clickhouse

Tags: primary-key, partition, clickhouse

I'm using clickhouse as my project underlying database and its `MergeTree` table enginge. I am trying to use  `Custom Partitioning Key` feature, and i created my table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(    
        UserID UUID,     
        ResourceID UUID,        
        TimeStamp DateTime,         
        Usage Int64,
        Version UInt32
)
ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree(Version)
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(TimeStamp)
ORDER BY (toYYYYMMDD(TimeStamp), UserID, ResourceID , TimeStamp)
```

The partition key is `toYYYYMM(TimeStamp)` which means clickhouse separate the data by month. In the meanwhile, i used `toYYYYMMDD(TimeStamp)` as the first column in primary index. I ingested 1 year data(about 30-40 million rows per month) for test.

When i query the data using `TimeStamp` filter condition, i get some confusing results.Here is my sql:

```
select count(*) from MyTable WHERE 
TimeStamp>=toDateTime('2019-01-30 00:00:00') 
and 
TimeStamp<toDateTime('2019-02-04 00:00:00')
```

It processed 75.62 million rows(whole data in January and February)！This means the query condition can hit the right partitions but miss the primary key. But if convert TimeStamp manually, like this:

```
select count(*) from MyTable WHERE
toYYYYMMDD(TimeStamp)>=toYYYYMMDD(toDateTime('2019-01-30 00:00:00')) 
and 
toYYYYMMDD(TimeStamp)<toYYYYMMDD(toDateTime('2019-02-04 00:00:00'))
```

Then it only processed 7 million rows(5-6 days data). This means the query condition hit the primary key.

**What confused me is that since clickhouse can hit the right partition without convert TimeStamp, why it can't hit the primary key automatically too? Do i really need to convert TimeStamp  manually?**

Answer (score 3):

Your table definition is adding too much information to the ORDER BY which is used to define the index into row data. I am guessing that ClickHouse cannot use the first part of the index when you specify the filter condition as toDateTime('2019-01-30 00:00:00'). It ends up reading the entire part as a result. Try defining your table instead as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
        UserID UUID,
        ResourceID UUID,
        TimeStamp DateTime,
        Usage Int64,
        Version UInt32 ) 
ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree(Version)
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(TimeStamp)
ORDER BY (UserID, ResourceID ,TimeStamp)
```

In this case you should see identical performance for both queries.  It's likely a bit slower in both cases than your fastest query where the filter exactly matches the first column of the index but quite a bit faster than the case where it does not match.

For further information about what's going on, look at the ClickHouse log, which is located in /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.log.  You'll see messages that tell you how much data ClickHouse actually reads to do the count.  Here's an example.

```
2019.08.29 14:46:39.507239 [ 41 ] {fc8cb747-5db2-40ac-afeb-32b61192de9a} <Debug> executeQuery: (from 127.0.0.1:49598) SELECT count(*) FROM MyTable WHERE (TimeStamp >= toDateTime('2019-09-30 00:00:00')) AND (TimeStamp < toDateTime('2019-10-04 00:00:00')) 
...
2019.08.29 14:46:39.518160 [ 41 ] {fc8cb747-5db2-40ac-afeb-32b61192de9a} <Debug> default.MyTable (SelectExecutor): Selected 2 parts by date, 2 parts by key, 63 marks to read from 11 ranges
2019.08.29 14:46:39.518739 [ 41 ] {fc8cb747-5db2-40ac-afeb-32b61192de9a} <Trace> default.MyTable (SelectExecutor): Reading approx. 516096 rows with 2 streams
```

In this case we can see that it selected a relatively small number of marks (i.e., granules of data) to read.  That gives you an idea how efficiently the primary key index is working.

Comment: Thanks for reply. As you say, the first column in primary index — `toYYYYMMDD(TimeStamp)` is just like a 'hidden' column, so we must match it by converting `TimeStamp` manually?

Comment: ClickHouse is pretty smart about converting functions.  When selecting parts it can identify that toYYYYMM() varies monotonically with the input DateTime value.  It will apply the conversion automatically to select parts.  I would actually expect it to use the first column in the index but it's possible that ClickHouse does not see

Comment: (Bad input) ClickHouse is pretty smart about converting functions. It tracks function monotonicity and can correctly apply conversions on DateTime values to select parts. I would actually expect it to do the same in the index but it seems it does not. Your more explicit filter conditions helped it out.  The system log messages were not helpful in this case, at least to me.